# Can an adjective be used as a subject in this example?

Tags: adjectives, plural-forms, subjects

In the example:

> The Iranian were interested in building and repairing their own house

Why is the adjective, *Iranian*, used as a subject?

Comment: "Iranian" can not be used as a plural noun. "Iranian*s*" can. And it means "Iranian people."

Comment: But how (the iranian) used as the subject that?

Comment: Your example sentence is bad grammar. It's either "*The Iranian**s** were interested...*" or "*The Iranian **was** interested...*". Either way, "Iranian" is a noun, the *demonym* for people from Iran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called a [*nominal adjective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective), where an adjective can be used as a noun. This is especially common when using an adjective that describes a group of people, where the adjective is used on its own to refer to a person/people that belong(s) to the group.

In this case, the word "Iranian" is being used on its own as a noun meaning "Iranian person." If you mean to speak about many Iranian people, you should use "Iranian*s*", with a plural "s" at the end, as singular "Iranian" only refers to one person.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The word "*Iranian*" here should be "*Iranians*", as pointed out in a comment by Esther. This is for subject-verb agreement in number. In that use it is not an adjective, but a noun, meaning "Iranian people". A somewhat similar but singular sentence could be constructed, for example

> The Iranian wanted tom purchase a car.

Here   "*Iranian*" is a noun meaning "person from Iran" or "person of Iranian  background", and is there subject of the sentence.

In general, adjectives of nationality are often used as nouns designating a person of that nationality or background. Even more generally, in English often the same word can function as either an adjective or as a noun, as the needs of the text dictate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct verb and noun forms for speaking about one person:

*The Iranian was interested in building and repairing his own house.*

This is the correct form for speaking about multiple people:

*The Iranians were interested in building and repairing their own houses.*

This is the basic form with correct noun-verb agreement:

*The man (singular) was...*

*The men (plural) were...*